# Sending different entity types to same Blazor component

Tags: components, blazor

I have a blazor component that I want to pass data retreived from a backend. Each set of data has a different entity name so I'm having trouble converting the entity to a generic type when it gets to the component. Where is my error? Thanks

Getting the following error on ChildData=@sysList in the parent:

Argument1: Cannot convert from Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementSystem[] to System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList[]

Parent

```
<ChildComponent ChildData=@sysList TItem=@Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementSystem</ChildComponent>
<ChildComponent ChildData=@unitList TItem=@Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementUnit</ChildComponent>
<ChildComponent ChildData=@groupList TItem=@Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementGroup</ChildComponent>

@functions {
    private Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementSystem[] sysList { get; set; }
    private Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementUnit[] unitList { get; set; }
    private Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementGroup[] groupList { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        sysList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementSystem[]>("/api/System/Index");
        unitList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementUnit[]>("/api/Unit/Index");
        groupList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Test2.Shared.Models.MeasurementGroup[]>("/api/Group/Index");
    }
}
```

Child

```
@typeparam TItem
@foreach (var data in ChildData)
{
    <p @data.Name>            
}

@functions {
    [Parameter] private IReadOnlyList<TItem>[] ChildData { get; set; }  
 }
```

Classes

```
public class MeasurementSystem
    {
        public int SystemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}

public class MeasurementUnit
    {
        public int UnitId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Factor { get; set; }
    public int Magnitude { get; set; }
    }
}

public class MeasurementGroup
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```